# Appending several panda dataframes are not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = r'c:\Temp\factory'
os.chdir(path)
files = os.listdir()
files_csv = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'csv']

x = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_csv:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
    x = x.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

I have used the same code before to concatenate CSV files but now it just does not work.

The problem i face is that only the content of one file makes it to the dataframe by name x.

I know i process all files and i expect the x dataframe to contain in total about 10000 rows but i only get the content of one file aproximatley 2000 rows.

My files typically looks like this:

```
Computer;Managed by;Given Name
cp1;user1;olle  
cp2;user2;niklas    
cp3;user3;kalle
```

Comment: Without even a sample of your csv files it is impossible to diagnose what the problem is. Also, appending is not the pandorable way of importing more than one file --- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38943704/509824) for a better approach.

Comment: I added example file. I tried your example but AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: I actually tried a modified version of your suggestion but i get the same result as my code. I only get one of the files  in my final dataframe and I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do something similar before. My solution would be:

```
x = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_csv:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
    x = pd.concat([x, data], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: If i set axis=0 using your code i get the same result as i get with my code

Comment: axis=1 seems to concatenate all CSV files horizontaly, each file adds new columns. I want to concatenate vertical this is why i changed axis to 0

Comment: Have you tried initializing x with your first file instead of a blank DataFrame?